# Getting a singular projection from a select query with multiple attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query that would do the following on the view `update_winnerlist` which is already GROUPed BY `item_index`:

```
SELECT email_id
(SELECT email_id, MIN(bid_amount)
   FROM update_winnerslist AS a1
  WHERE a1.item_index = 10 )
```

I need to perform the above in a single query as I am using it in a trigger to update a table.

Comment: the update_winnerslist table contains mail_id,item_index,bid_amount attributes.The table is already grouped by item_index values.
I am trying to get the email_id for item_index=10 with the lowest bid_amount i.e. the email_id of the person who made the lowest bid on item_index 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select top 1 email_id from update_winnerslist
 where item_index = 10 order by bid_amount desc
```